# Adding page curl animation to view when button is tapped on Appcelerator.Titanium

Tags: iphone, animation, titanium, appcelerator, page-curl

I'm a newbie in appcelerator.titanium. I started development from today onwards.

My problem is, 
I want to display a page curl transition effect when a button is tapped on one of my view.

I used the following code for doing this. But the application is crashed. I searched a lot in SO and titanium documentation. But couldn't find a solution.

```
//This function returns a window

function ApplicationWindow()
{
    //load component dependencies
    var FirstView = require('ui/common/FirstView');

    //create component instance
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff'
    });

    //construct UI
    var firstView = new FirstView();
    self.add(firstView);

    //Adding button for displaying view 2
    var button1 = Ti.UI.createButton({
        height  : '50',
        width   : '50%',
        top     : '70%',
        title : 'Add Child'
    });

    //Adding event listner for button
    button1.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        var view = createView();
        win.add(view);
    });
    self.add(button1);

    //creating second view
    function createView()
    {
        var view = Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundColor : '#aabbcc'
        });

            //creating button for view 2
        var button2 = Ti.UI.createButton({
        height  : '50',
        width   : '50%',
        top     : '70%',
        title   : 'Show Curl'
    });

    //Adding event listner for button
    button2.addEventListener('click',function(e)
    {
            //creating animation
        var animation = Titanium.UI.createAnimation({
        transition :  Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.CURL_UP
            });
        animation.backgroundColor = 'black';
        animation.duration = 1000;
        var animationHandler = function() {
             animation.removeEventListener('complete',animationHandler);
             animation.backgroundColor = 'orange';
             view.animate(animation);
        };
        animation.delay = 5000
        animation.addEventListener('complete',animationHandler);
        view.animate(animation);
     });

     view.add(button2);
     return view;
    }
    return self;
}

//creating window and opening
var win = ApplicationWindow();
win.open();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this module instead: http://support.appcelerator.com/kb/119/tickets

It's all done for you..